# MS Access How to bold select items in ListBox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a requirement to display in Bold, items in the ListBox that have at least one child item in the database. How do I make an item display in BOLD in ListBox?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a subform instead. You do not have that level of control with a listbox.

Comment: A subform instead of a listbox. Otherwise you could append a character to your description column, for example, `* Joe Blogs`

Comment: If you use a subform you could use a Datasheet View or Continuous form view and then use Conditional Formatting. If you need a way to let users select multiple records you'll need to add a checkbox that's bound to a field. Otherwise you could allow click or double click to select a single record.